# Qstackedwidget - импорт своего класса, PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer, qlayout, qstackedwidget

Господа, есть вопрос ...

> В общем:
>
> 1. файл **`gui.py`** (описание формы приложения).
> 2. файл **`main.py`** (общий принцип работы приложения).
> 3. файл **`video.py`** (это `stackedwidget` c `currenet(1)`).

Так я, для нормальной конструкции всего кода, хочу разделить отдельные виджеты на разных страницах на разные классы и хранить в отдельных файлах. И все эти отдельные классы с описанием функционала импортить в **`main.py`** в главный класс.

Вот как прописать класс из **`video.py`** чтобы он работал в **`main.py`**?

---

**gui.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(534, 325)
        Form.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(1, 203, 170);")
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(Form)
        self.stackedWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 70, 491, 241))
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        self.page = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page.setObjectName("page")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 70, 311, 101))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(25)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page)
        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setObjectName("page_2")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page_2)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 331, 191))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(30)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.page_2)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 110, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 85, 255);")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 20, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 85, 255);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 20, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 85, 0);")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "Simple first page"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Video on opencv"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Form", "start"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Main"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Video"))
```

---

**main.py**

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from simple.gui import Ui_Form

class MainClass(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(lambda : self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda : self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainClass()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**video.py**

```
import cv2
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
from simple.gui import Ui_Form


class VideoStream(QWidget, Ui_Form):
    # class constructor
    def __init__(self):
        # call QWidget constructor
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        # create a timer
        self.timer = QTimer()
        # set timer timeout callback function
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.viewCam)
        # set control_bt callback clicked  function
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.controlTimer)

    # view camera
    def viewCam(self):
        # read image in BGR format
        ret, image = self.cap.read()
        # convert image to RGB format
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        # get image infos
        height, width, channel = image.shape
        step = channel * width
        # create QImage from image
        qImg = QImage(image.data, width, height, step, QImage.Format_RGB888)
        # show image in img_label
        self.label_2.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(qImg))

    # start/stop timer
    def controlTimer(self):
        # if timer is stopped
        if not self.timer.isActive():
            # create video capture
            self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
            # start timer
            self.timer.start(20)

        # if timer is started
        else:
            # stop timer
            self.timer.stop()
            self.cap.release()
```

Comment: Вы хотите вставить VideoStream в качестве виджета в форму главного окна MainClass?

Comment: я хочу вставить уже описанный виджет VideoStream в класс MainClass. Все это для удобства чтения кода. Описание в отдельном файле.

Comment: В stackedWidget, или куда?

Comment: в stackedwidget добавлен label (он описан в gui.py). В этот label я как раз хочу вставить экземпляр класса Video. Например, я могу создать экземпляр класса в другом файле, импортировав его (класс) в этот файл. А с pyqt я не знаком толком и найти не могу такую реализацию.

Comment: В label ничего нельзя вставить, он не является контейнером для виджетов. Вы можете добавить ваш Video-виджет в self.page.

Comment: self.ui.image_label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(qImg)). вот такой код вставляет в label потокове видео посредством opencv.

Comment: Картинка это не виджет, или вы хотите выводить изображение из VideoClass в label?

Comment: Точно так!)))))

Comment: Короче, товарищ партизан, я вас понял, вам надо вместо label на page вставить VideoStream. Ответ дал

Comment: надо переварить))) я не то чтобы партизан, просто новичок и, возможно, не правильно формулирую вопросы)))

Comment: Все-таки хочется увидеть реализацию через помещение в label, т.к. без stakedwidget я без проблем в label помещаю видео

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я отметит для вас места где внес изменения.

У меня все модули в одном каталоге. Когда проверите мой пример, разместите свои модули как вам будет угодно.

Чтобы разместить что-то в `label_2`, создайте `layout` наследованный от `label_2` и размещайте туда что хотите.

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
#from simple.gui import Ui_Form
from gui import Ui_Form                                       # +

from video import VideoStream                                 # +++

class MainClass(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(lambda : self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda : self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0))

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.label_2)
        self.videoStream = VideoStream(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.videoStream)

        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.videoStream.controlTimer)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainClass()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**video.py**

```
import cv2
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
#from simple.gui import Ui_Form


class VideoStream(QWidget):                                # - , Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):                       # + parent
        super().__init__(parent)                           # + parent
        self.parent = parent                               # + parent

# ---       self.setupUi(self)                                                # ----

        # create a timer
        self.timer = QTimer()
        # set timer timeout callback function
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.viewCam)
        # set control_bt callback clicked  function
#        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.controlTimer)                  # ----

    # view camera
    def viewCam(self):
        # read image in BGR format
        ret, image = self.cap.read()
        # convert image to RGB format
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        # get image infos
        height, width, channel = image.shape
        step = channel * width
        # create QImage from image
        qImg = QImage(image.data, width, height, step, QImage.Format_RGB888)
        # show image in img_label
        self.parent.label_2.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(qImg))                   # self.parent.label_2

    # start/stop timer
    def controlTimer(self):
        # if timer is stopped
        if not self.timer.isActive():
            # create video capture
            self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
            # start timer
            self.timer.start(20)

        # if timer is started
        else:
            # stop timer
            self.timer.stop()
            self.cap.release()
```

---

**gui.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(534, 325)
        Form.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(1, 203, 170);")
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(Form)
        self.stackedWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 70, 491, 241))
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        self.page = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page.setObjectName("page")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 70, 311, 101))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(25)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page)
        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setObjectName("page_2")

        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page_2)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 331, 191))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(30)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")


        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.page_2)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 110, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 85, 255);")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 20, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 85, 255);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 20, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 85, 0);")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "Simple first page"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Video on opencv"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Form", "start"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Main"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Video"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему-то pushButton_3 (которая "Start") не кликабельна...

Comment: @Артем скопируйте мои модули, проверьте работу, а затем внесете изменения с свои модули, вникая в каждую строку. Порядок строк важен.

Comment: понял. Спасибо за Ваш труд.

Comment: @Артем вопрос решен или вам что-то не понятно?

Comment: мне только не понятно вот что: если все делать в одном окне без stackedWidget, то не нужен layout. Я помещаю в окно только label и pushButton. Далее я в label помещаю self.ui.label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(qImg)) это и там идет видео.

Comment: @Артем вы спросили: `хочется увидеть реализацию через помещение в label...`,  я показал как это делать. Мой пример работает у вас ? То что вы уточняете я не совсем понимаю, т.к. вариантов что-то сделать много.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107410/discussion-between--and-s-nick).

Comment: @Артем если у вас есть другие вопросы - `Задайте новый вопрос`

Answer (score 1):

Если вы редактируете через QtDesigner, то описал ниже, если программно, то VideoStream можно сразу добавить в Ui_Form.

Добавьте в self.page лейаут, например QVBoxLayout, он нужен чтобы растянуть его содержимое на весь родительский виджет:

```
lass Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        ...
        self.page = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.page.setLayout(layout)        
        ...
```

Далее в main.py

```
from video import VideoStream

class MainClass(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        # Добавим VideoStream в лейаут на self.page
        self.page.layout().addWidget(VideoStream())
```